# Smoothing mouse animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to create a simple animation based on my mouse movement. An object that is placed in the center of the screen should pull away from the center based on my mouse movement. But when i try to do that the object jitters around a lot despite the mouse movement being smooth.

I have created a fiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ahof0gLc/

The object is moved as follows when the mouse moves:

```
animX += event.movementX||event.mozMovementX||event.webkitMovementX||0;
```

It is then pulled back toward the center like so:

```
if (animX) animX *= Math.pow(0.99, delta);
```

I have tried several methods. But because the mouse movement is counteracting the deceleration it jitters a lot. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect it to do while interacting with the mouse?

Comment: It should behave as it does now but without jittering

Comment: If you're trying to model a springy pull, you need a spring model for the pull.  It should based on where the mouse is, rather than how much it moved during the last event window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with a really hacky spring model.  Using mouse over and mouse leave to track mouse.

https://jsfiddle.net/eex3aphm/

---

You have a fight between your mousemove and your animation.

I changed your mouse movement handler to use a temporary variable to hold the movement:

```
var pullX = 0;
var onMouseMove = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        pullX = event.movementX||event.mozMovementX||event.webkitMovementX||0;
};
```

Then moved the update to the deceleration equation:

```
animX = (animX + pullX) * Math.pow(0.99, delta);
pullX = 0;
```

This keeps you from messing with your deceleration on mouse move.

https://jsfiddle.net/r57t7v3o/

Comment: Its better but when I move the mouse slowly it still jitters

Comment: I think the core problem is in how you are using the event.  Mouse events are jittery; your code is decelerating whenever there is no mouse event.  What do you want the mouse to do to the square when it's in the box?

Comment: I want it to drag it away from the center a little when you move your mouse in either direction. The idea is that the further the mouse drags from the center the harder it gets to drag the square

Comment: See my comment in main thread.  You need to model this with (toy) physics.  Your pull towards the middle is right enough in the absence of a force, but your pull away is wrong.

Comment: Im trying to make sense of it. How do I turn the mouse position into an acceleration?

Comment: You'll need to adjust the constants for sure, and rewrite it as non-crappy code (jsfiddle makes me a bad programmer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162358/discussion-between-jim-baldwin-and-sidney-de-vries).